# Is there a Limit for the Facebook Public Available API?

Tags: facebook, api

IS there a limit of connections and time of requests I can send to the Facebook public API?

I do not need to get private informations of the logged in users, but only some public information.

I will get a LOT of data, and I will have to do a LOT of request.

Is there a limit I have to consider?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is officially no limit that is specified by the Facebook Dev team. However, users did face issues in the past while trying to pull large amounts of data. I believe there was also a bug that was being tracked some time back regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook limits API access on multiple levels as e.g. per User ID and per App ID. The calculate a 'score‘ per app that defines individual API limits. This depends e.g. on the number of active users but also on the 'smartness' of the requests as well as their CPU and memory usage on the Facebook side. See this for more details https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/api-rate-limiting/